# Why is my drop down button not hiding after I have clicked outside of the box although the JS is identical to another working dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-listener

I have two dropdown menus. One of them is not hiding after I click outside of it although it is supposed to close because of the window event listener. Besides that, the first dropdown already works fine (`class="dropdownCountry"`).
The one not working is this: [image]
Are they somehow conflicting each other?

p.s. The signatures are fake.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}


/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function showCountries() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownCountry").classList.toggle("show");
}
  
// Close the Country dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    // if (!event.target.matches('dropbtnCountry') || !event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtnCountry')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentCountry"); 
        // var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentCountry");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                // alert(dropdowns[i]);
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
}

function writeCountryContents(countryChoice) {
        document.getElementById('buttonContent').innerHTML = countryChoice;
}

function writeTravelContents(dropDownChoice) {
        document.getElementById('traveledDistance').innerHTML = dropDownChoice;
}
```

```css
 .dropbtnCountry  {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
 .dropbtnCountry:hover, .dropbtnCountry:focus  {
    background-color: #2980B9;
  }
  
 .dropdownCountry {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
 .dropdown-contentCountry {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
 .dropdown-contentCountry a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
 .dropdownCountry a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
  
  .show {display: block;}


  /* TEST  */

  /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
  .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
  }
  
  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
  
  /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
  .show {display:block;}

@page {
    size: A4;
  }
  
  * {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .maintable {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  table.maintable tr,
  table.maintable th,
  table.maintable td {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  
  main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  
  table.signaturetable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  
  table.signaturetable td.signatures {
    padding-right: 100px;
  }
  
  section {
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  
  #aktdatum {
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .signature {
    max-width: 200px; /* or any custom size */
    max-height: 200px; 
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Groß BauBau Doku</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Source code by Svetlin Ivanov">
    <meta name="author" content="Svetlin!">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/btest.css?v=1654539501">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dropdown.css?v=1654539501">
    <script src="/dropdown.js1654539501"></script>

 </head>

<body>
    <main>
      <table class="maintable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="10" rowspan="1">
              <h1>:D &amp; Groß BauBau GmbH</h1>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="10" rowspan="1">
              <p>Marktstraße 8 , D-49006 Darmstadt</p>
              <p>Tel.: +49 (0) 0000 0000 – Telefax +49 (0) 0000 0000</p>
              <p>Ansprechpartner Carsten Schmidt: +49 (0) 000 201 0000</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="10" rowspan="1">
              <p>Arbeitszeitnachweis</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
              <div class="dropdownCountry">
<button onclick="showCountries()" class="dropbtnCountry"><p id="buttonContent">Land Auswählen</p></button>
<div id="myDropdownCountry" class="dropdown-contentCountry">
  <a href="#" id="de" onclick="writeCountryContents('Deutschland')">Deutschland</a>
  <a href="#" id="at" onclick="writeCountryContents('Österreich')">Österreich</a>
  <a href="#" id="ch" onclick="writeCountryContents('Schweiz')">Schweiz</a>
</div>
</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
              <p>Mitarbeiter:<a></a>aus Stammdaten</p>
              <p></p>
              <p>Bestellnummer:<a></a>aus Arbeitsauftrag</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
              <p>Maschinentyp: <a></a>Freitext</p>
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
              <p>Equipment:<a></a>Freitext</p>
              <p></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>Anreise / Abreise</p>
              <p>Datum</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>von</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>bis</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>Pause</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>Std.</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">
              <p>Kommentar</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><a></a>
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><a></a>
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>berechnen</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" rowspan="1"><a></a>
              <p>Freitext</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>Arbeitszeit</p>
              <p>Datum</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>von</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>bis</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>Pause</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>Std.</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p><p></p><p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">
              <p>Kommentar</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p>berechnen</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">
              <p>Freitext</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
         
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p> </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              <p></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
     <!-- DROPDOWN -->
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
              <p></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
              
              <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><p id="traveledDistance">gefahrene Kilometer</p></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content show">
      <a href="#" onclick="writeTravelContents('Privat PKW')">privat PKW</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="writeTravelContents('firmen PKW')">firmen PKW</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="writeTravelContents('Mietwagen')">Mietwagen</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="writeTravelContents('gefahrene Kilometer zum Eingeben')">gefahrene Kilometer zum Eingeben</a>
    </div>
  </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
  
  
        </tbody>
  
      </table>
    </main>
    <section>
      <table class="signaturetable">
        <tbody><tr colspan="10" id="aktdatum">
          <td>Aktuelles Datum</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="10">
          <td class="signatures">
            <hr class="line1"><span class="signature">Ort und Datum</span>
          </td>
          <td class="signatures">
            <hr class="line1">Unterschrift Baustellenleiter<br><img src="https://imgs.search.brave.com/vQHYuegJAQlqKFCGmKWQDkPQggsktZeB87PBxxX8br8/rs:fit:697:225:1/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly90c2Uz/Lm1tLmJpbmcubmV0/L3RoP2lkPU9JUC5h/UWVLWUVTV3ZSNElJ/d0NIclFZMmVRQUFB/QSZwaWQ9QXBp" class="signature">
          </td>
          <td class="signatures">
            <hr class="line1">Unterschrift Monteur<br><img src="https://www.morebusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/handwritten-email-signature.jpg" class="signature">
          </td>
        </tr>
       
      </tbody></table>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dropdown.js"></script>  
  </body>
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-contentCountry");` is just the first dropdown, not the second one. The second one has `class="dropdown-content"`.

Comment: The first button also doesn't work until after you've clicked outside it. I think this is because clicking on the button runs both the button onclick and the window.onclick, and they each toggle the `show` class so they undo each other.

Comment: Hey @Barmar, good to meet you here! I have tried separating them in different functions, I also tried to toggle only one of them with logical or which still stands there commented out. I couldn't figure out a way to make it work. 

Do you have any hint on how to do it?

Comment: Use the same class for both buttons and divs. Then the loop will close both of them.

Comment: Also use `event.stopPropagation()` in the button's onclick, so that the window.onclick isn't executed to undo it.